# hibernate & jpa : table with composite primary key : auto increment problem

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have thoses entities :

```
@Entity
public class Carburant implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_carburant")
    private long id;
    private String nom;
    private String description;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="carburant")
    private Set<HistCarb> stations ;

    public Carburant() {
        super();
    }
}
```

2

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Station")
public class Station implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_station")
    private long id ;
    private String nom;
    private String ville;
    private String adresse;

    @Transient
    private boolean nul = false;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="station")
    private Set<HistCarb> historiques ;

    public Station() {
        super();
    }
}
```

3

```
@Entity

public class HistCarb implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id",updatable=false,nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private Date date;
    private Integer prix;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_station")

    private Station station ;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_carburant")
    private Carburant carburant ;


    public HistCarb() {
        super();

    }
}
```

class diagram :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwmYD.png)

and the problem her is : hibernate give me this sql code for table HistCarb:

```
create table HistCarb (
       id bigint not null,
        date datetime,
        prix integer,
        id_station bigint not null auto_increment,
        id_carburant bigint not null,
        primary key (id_station, id, id_carburant)
    ) engine=InnoDB
```

with id_station auto_increment but I want that hibernate generate only the column id as auto_increment field as actualy I mentioned in the entity 3
I hobe someone can help me with this issue .
I didn't use an embedded ID for entity 3 I think that we can  do it without an embedded ID because I found it very diffuclt to implement and when I tried to use an embedded ID for this situation it gives some errors .

Comment: Why would you mark the FK fields as `@Id` when having an auto-increment field as the `@Id`? Makes no sense at all

Answer (score 0):

In `HistCarb` you have `@Id` on 3 fields, that's why you get a composite key. Remove `@Id` from `station` and `carburant` like this:

```
@Entity
public class HistCarb implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id",updatable=false,nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private Date date;
    private Integer prix;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_station")

    private Station station ;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_carburant")
    private Carburant carburant ;


    public HistCarb() {
        super();

    }
}
```